# How do I make Gulp put files in appropriate directories in the build after minifying?

Tags: gulp

In my gulpfile so far, I am minifying the Javascript code using [uglify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify) and using [sourcemaps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sourcemaps) to keep the traces. The problem is that all the files are going into the root of the `build` directory. I would like Gulp to create appropriate directories under the build directory same as they are copied from.

Here is my code so far:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    javascript_minify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    files = {
        javascript: ['controllers/*.js', 'directives/*.js', 'services/*.js', 'app.js'],
        html: [], // to be added
        css: [] // to be added
    };

gulp.task('javascript-minify', function () {
    gulp.src(files.javascript)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(javascript_minify())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});
```

As explained earlier, here is the visual of the problem:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to pass `base` as second param in source...

```
gulp.task('javascript-minify', function () {
    gulp.src(files.javascript, {base: "."})
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(javascript_minify())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});
```

That should help you.